Why could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior?
My intention is: when I press the buttom labeled "STANDARD BOTTOM SHEET", I want the Standard sheet dialog to be shown.
I'm trying to use a bottom sheet modal dialog, but for some reason, everytime I try to debug it, I get the following exception message:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample, PID: 18368
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42 in br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:layout/fragment_main_menu: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:649)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2896)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1740)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:112)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1129)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample.databinding.FragmentMainMenuBinding.inflate(FragmentMainMenuBinding.java:70)
    at br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample.MainMenuFragment.onCreateView(MainMenuFragment.kt:16)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:557)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2945)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3148)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:272)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1455)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3034)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2952)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:350)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1545)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3786)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2412)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:238)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:357)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8149)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:957) (Ask Gemini)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:647)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030114 a=20}, theme={InheritanceMap=[id=0x7f110274br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.StackOverflowExample, id=0x7f11024cbr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar, id=0x7f110245br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.MaterialComponents, id=0x7f110065br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.Theme.MaterialComponents, id=0x7f1100a5br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V21.Theme.MaterialComponents, id=0x7f110091br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents, id=0x7f110092br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Bridge, id=0x7f110138br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Platform.MaterialComponents, id=0x7f11020bbr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f11004bbr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100b8br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100b5br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100afbr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100adbr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100a1br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f1100babr.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat, id=0x7f110136br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Platform.AppCompat, id=0x7f110141br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Platform.V25.AppCompat, id=0x103022eandroid:style/Theme.Material.NoActionBar, id=0x1030224android:style/Theme.Material, id=0x1030005android:style/Theme], Themes=[br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.StackOverflowExample, forced, br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample:style/Theme.AppCompat.Empty, forced, android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DarkActionBar, forced]}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:600)
    at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:81)
    at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.<init>(BottomSheetBehavior.java:358)
    ... 46 more

And here is the layout xml, the main menu fragment, that is giving me trouble
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_standard_bottom_sheet"
        android:text="STANDARD BOTTOM SHEET"
        ... />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_modal_bottom_sheet"
        android:text="MODAL BOTTOM SHEET"
        ... />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cdl_test_modal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cl_test_modal"
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.BottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
                android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
                ... />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_test_modal"
                android:text="THIS IS A STANDARD BOTTOM SHEET"
                ... />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

The bindings
class MainMenuFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentMainMenuBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, group: ViewGroup?, saved: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentMainMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, group, false)

        val bottomSheet = binding.clTestModal
        val modalBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        modalBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN

        binding.btnStandardBottomSheet.setOnClickListener {
            modalBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}

The main activity xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

the main activity bindings
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}

The manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StackOverflowExample"
        tools:targetApi="34">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

The Theme.StackOverflowExample (Day and Night respectively)
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.StackOverflowExample" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.StackOverflowExample" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>

the project build.gradle.kts
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
}

the module build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "br.com.thyerry.stackoverflowexample"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

and, finnaly, the libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
materialVersion = "1.8.0"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.7.7"
navigationUiKtx = "2.7.7"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationUiKtx" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

I'm putting all these files here because I really searched out there for a solution, and every solution I found (that didn't work for me), each suggested changes in different files, so there is all files that can be important to diagnose the causes of this problem.
How did i get here: Actually, I was making this project to be used as an example for another question I wanted to ask about Bottom Sheets (see the project name on the exception), but in the main project, I'm having problems with the BottomSheetDialogFragment instead. Turns out that this side project troubled me more than the main one.
The funny part is: in the main project I have a fragment with this exact implementation of the standard bottom sheet, and it works perfectly! But in the side project it simply don't. And I'm losing my mind. Please help me.

Please include the entire stack trace.

Updated! Sorry about that.

Your error says java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 3, indicating a problem with your theme. Do you actually override anything in your Theme.StackOverflowExample? Please include the theme in your question.

Added the themes files just bellow the manifest. And I hadn't made any changes on Theme.StackOverflowExample. They are as they were since I create the project with no activity.
